PowerBI DAX measure to sum only records associated with the MAX of a grouping
I have data similar like below:
ID  Month       Place   Female Students Male Students   Total
1   January     Place_1 250 10  260
2   January     Place_2 50  50  100
3   February    Place_1 100 50  150
4   February    Place_1 175 25  200
5   February    Place_2 100 100 200
6   February    Place_2 200 50  250
7   March       Place_1 200 50  250
8   March       Place_1 10  190 200
9   March       Place_2 100 200 300
10  March       Place_2 300 100 400

I wanted to a measure to calculate the summation of Total Students considering the MAX grouped by Month and Place. I was able to do this using:
Sum of Total Max =
SUMX (
SUMMARIZE ( Table,Table[Month], Table[Place], "Max Total", MAX(Table[Total] )),
[Max Total])


However, I also wanted a measure to calculate the Total Female Students  considering only the rows of where the Total is the Maximum of the grouping. In my case, I would add the rows of ID: 1,2,4,6,7 and 10. Can you please help me with a DAX code to achieve this?

I also want to get the list of ID for which the total is the Maximum Total of the grouping (month, place)?


I am not sure if my question is clear, but feel free to drop me a request so I can further explain. Please find the PBI file here 
Thank you very much.
I tried this:
Total Female Students Max = //Try this one
VAR MaxTotal =
    MAXX (
        SUMMARIZE ( Table, Table[Month], Table[Place], "Max Total", MAX ( Table[Total] ) ),
        [Max Total]
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table[Female Students] ),
        FILTER ( Table, Table[Total] = MaxTotal )
    )

But It did not work as I expected.

This solution works as per the current question asked, as measure can hold only one aggregated value. Create summary table and flow below step to get the output.

create summary table, added unique id by combining three columns palce, month and max(total) in summary table.

In main table also create new column using the palce,month and total

use join table based on new column created on both table, this would give the output as expected.


in below image ID is form Main table rest all from Summary table.

